# How to make correct many-to-many link between ingredients and dishes?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, many-to-many

I have ingredients (for example, chicken and potatoes) with their amounts in storage. And i have have a dish, which consists of 100g of chicken and 200g of potatoes.

I guess classes should look like:

```
class Ingredients(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    amount = models.IntegerField()

class Dish(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredients) 
    amount = ????
```

So the question is how to give certain amount to certain ingredient?

I don't really know how to solve it

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [through table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through). The `through` model would contain relations to `Ingredient` and `Dish`, and the ingredient amount as an additional field. This way you gain the advantages of the many-to-many field while also being able to include the important meta data (ingredient amount).

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand how to structure this data I think you need to step back from Django for a minute and think about how the database tables would look like.

In relational databases, tables can't natively have many-to-many relationships. Instead in order to simulate them, intermediate tables are created.

Imagine that you have a list of dishes and a list of ingredients, and you wanted to create relationships between the two in a way that a dish could be connected to multiple ingredients and vice versa, without duplicated data and without conflicts.

Take for example a Pizza. I'm going to register ingredients one by one:

```
Pizza - Dough
Pizza - Tomato
Pizza - Mozzarella
Pizza - Origano
```

Ok now imagine that the ID of the pizza dish was 1 and each Ingredient had their own unique ID. Then you could represent the same associations using the IDs like:

```
1 - 1 (Dough)
1 - 2 (Tomato)
1 - 3 (Mozzarella)
1 - 4 (Origano)
```

Now imagine that there are other dishes, each with their own ingredients, and some ingredients are repeated across dishes.

```
1 - 1 (Dough)
1 - 2 (Tomato)
1 - 3 (Mozzarella)
1 - 4 (Origano)
34 - 1
34 - 12
34 - 78
34 - 3
41 - 2
41 - 48
41 - 23
...
```

In the example above, each ID on the left represents the ID of a dish and each ID on the right represents the ID of an ingredient. In both cases you can see that some IDs are repeated, that's because each Dish and each Ingredient is not limited to one appearance, making this by all accounts a many-to-many relationship.

Now let's say that we also want to add some information about the ingredients amount. I'm gonna re-use the Pizza example.

```
1 - 1 (Dough) (200g)
1 - 2 (Tomato) (50g)
1 - 3 (Mozzarella) (50g)
1 - 4 (Origano) (a pinch)
```

So this is your case. You want to create a structure in Django that allows you to add information about quantities that is **specific to the relationship** and not specific to the Dish or Ingredient.

You do that with a Django `through table`, which is a representation of the intermediate table that we discussed here above. Here's an example of implementation:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Dish(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredients, through="appname.IngredientDish") 

class DishIngredient(models.Model):
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="dish_ingredient")
    dish = models.ForeignKey(Dish, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="dish_ingredient")
    amount = models.FloatField()
```

So now let's say that you have a dish and want to add an ingredient to it:

```
dish = Dish.objects.create(name="pizza")
ingredient = Ingredient.objects.create("tomato")

DishIngredient.objects.create(dish=dish, ingredient=ingredient, amount="50")
```

There are other ways to read/write from the through table. You can also create a relationship with `dish.add(ingredient)` for example and then access the object later to add an amount.

I invite you to checkout the [examples in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) as they're very thorough and will certainly help you understand all options at your disposal with Django's m2m relationships!